# WCF and Javascript CORS issues unable to set origin wildcard

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf

I have the following method:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "data/{id}/{test}")]
public Person GetData(string id, string test)
{
    IncomingWebRequestContext woc = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
    OutgoingWebResponseContext cow = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;


    cow.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if(woc.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Log.Info("I'm here");
        cow.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        cow.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE,GET,OPTIONS");
        cow.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        cow.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");

    }

    try
    {
        Log.Info("GetData function invoked...");

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Log.Error(err.ToString());
    }
    // lookup person with the requested id 
    return new Person()
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(id),
        Name = "Leo Messi"
    };
}
```

It is a WCF service running as a windows service.

There is no web.config only an app.config.

I'm making a javascript xmlhttp GET request however I'm coming across CORS issue it.

At preflight it is erroring out so it nevermakes the GET request.

Here is my javascript:

```
function Runreq()
{
    var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://xx.x.x.xxx:8888/RestWCFServiceLibrary/data/2/2",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Yo": "Hi",
    "ID": "123",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "746cdba0-c05e-f341-b183-7ce2bfd12bd2"
  }
}
```

This still errors out, I'm unable to make the request happen.

I have tried jsonp but that doesn't work because I need to use custom headers.

I have full control of the end point service so I can change whatever I need but currently it doesn't respond with a 200 message, if I use POSTMAN itworks no problem.

The request is happening from a browser that runs apache locally and the sites address is localhost the request is being made to a windows machine that runs the service.

What specifcally do I change to make this CORS request work?

I have a appconfig but no web.config file.

this is my app.config that is in my windows service project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="RestWCFServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior" name="RestWCFServiceLibrary.RestWCFServiceLibrary">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestWCFServiceLibrary.IRestWCFServiceLibrary" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8888/RestWCFServiceLibrary/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestWCFServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```